# Python add two cursors with mplcursors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, mplcursors

I want to use mplcursors to show both x and y value with a label information, on the same tooltip.
Actually I used two cursor but the box information are overlapped.
Here is my code example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from pandas import DataFrame


df = DataFrame(
  [("Alice", 163, 54),
   ("Bob", 174, 67),
   ("Charlie", 177, 73),
   ("Diane", 168, 57)],
   columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

scatter1=df.plot.scatter("height", "weight")
c1=mplcursors.cursor(scatter1)

mplcursors.cursor().connect(
    "add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(df["name"][sel.target.index]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could leave out the first cursor (c1) and add all information to the other cursor. Like so:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(
    [("Alice", 163, 54),
     ("Bob", 174, 67),
     ("Charlie", 177, 73),
     ("Diane", 168, 57)],
    columns=["name", "height", "weight"])
scatter1 = df.plot.scatter("height", "weight")
mplcursors.cursor(scatter1, hover=True).connect("add",
    lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(
        f'{df["name"][sel.target.index]}\nHeight: {df["height"][sel.target.index] / 100} m\nWeight: {df["weight"][sel.target.index]} kg'))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]